# Bootstrap 3 Image hover on another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 responsive layout, I am trying to achieve hover effect image to another.

```
<div id="sliderimages" class="container-fluid">         
  <div class="container" id="imageSlider">
    <img class="normal img-responsive" src="images/img_03.jpg">
    <img class="hover img-responsive" src="images/img_03-3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is the css code I use on the file.

```
#sliderimages{
background-image: url(../images/wood-4.jpg);
height: auto;
}

#sliderimages img.normal, #sliderimages:hover img.hover
{

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sliderimages img.hover, #sliderimages:hover img.normal
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The code works up to the hover effect. However, I can't get the images on top of each other. If i use `position:absolute;` on the hover image, it starts displace. I know that I can achieve the image on top of each other by setting height to a `integer` instead of `auto`. But that strips the image responsiveness on different devices.

Anyone render some help?

Comment: not clear for what you except, on top of each other, than which one to trigger when hover?

Comment: .hover class image's opacity goes to zero. .normal class image stay behind hover image

Comment: still don't understand. maybe a mockup image will explain if you can do that. is this what you look for? http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: @Kush By any chance you are trying to fit all the images w.r.t width and height in the container?